# Calculate slopes between two points

Tags: r

How can I calculate the slope between two data points?

My values look like this:

```
2010 |  2011 |  2012 |  2013
23.5 |  4    |  0    |  1.5
```

and so on. So, to each year belongs a value - AUC.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A bit ugly solution,

```
lm(y ~ x)$coeff[[2]]
```

Answer (score 9):

try this formula

```
diff(y) / diff(x)
```

Comment: Seemed like it would work. However, If I apply this to a column, I get an error that the result returned is one item shorter than the input. I don't understand why that one isn't NA and didn't notice anything about this in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
    id = 1:6,
    year = 1995:2000,
    y =  c(3,33,333,33333,333,3) # 20:25
)

df2 <- tibble(
  id = 1:5,
  year = 1996:2000,
  slope_y = diff(df$y) / diff(df$year)
)

df2
```

Just trying the following returns an error:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(slope_y = diff(df$y) / diff(df$year))
```

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `slope_y`.
> i `slope_y = diff(df$y)/diff(df$year)`.
> i `slope_y` must be size 6 or 1, not 5.

I'm reasoning that the first item in `df` does not have a slope so a result of the incorrect number of records returns an error. I don't know a way to ignore that error and just insert NA instead. If someone knows a way please comment. One workaround is to create a new data frame based on the two vectors. I imagine if there were gaps in some years this might produce unexpected results. I did not test that situation. Good luck folks.

Comment: Was able to add a non-consecutive year col by way of `Year = df_tmp$Year[df_tmp$Year>min(df_tmp$Year)]`